# Java thread not working second time

Tags: java, multithreading

I know this is a common question but I couldn't find solution for my particular case.
I have a `class Player implements Runnable` which is used to play .wav sounds when a button is clicked.

Here is the `run()` method.

```
public void run() { 



    auline.start();

    int nBytesRead = 0;
    byte[] abData = new byte[EXTERNAL_BUFFER_SIZE];

    try { 
        while (nBytesRead != -1) { 
            nBytesRead = audioInputStream.read(abData, 0, abData.length);
            if (nBytesRead >= 0) 
                auline.write(abData, 0, nBytesRead);
        } 
    } catch (IOException e) { 
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    } finally { 
        auline.drain();
        auline.close();
    } 

}
```

And this is where I create and run the thread itself.

```
soundButtons[j].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JButton button = (JButton) e.getSource();
                int index = Integer.parseInt(button.getName());
                Thread t = new Thread(samples[index]);
                t.start();

            }
        });
```

The problem is that java doesn't allow to start the same thread two times. But i can't figure out why it isn't working because every time I am creating a new reference object `new Thread(samples[index]);` . Are there any suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please share minimal testable code.

Comment: I suppose samples[index] references the same Runnable each time.

Comment: Here is the whole Runnable class http://www.codesend.com/view/b1fccef31dc8fa1d740f8c748ca11d4a/

Comment: If samples[index] references the same runnable, i think the problem is that the init() method is only called once. Like this, you will read -1 from the audioInputStream on the second call to run().

Comment: But init method is for browsing the sound file . It is more sufficient to browse the file once , and then use it multiple times than to browse it and destroy every time.

Comment: You've run out of Stream. You either need to close the old and create a new Stream or see if you can mark and reset the old Stream, before you can try reading from it again. Note, not all Streams support mark/reset, so the most reliable and safest way to handle this is to close it when done with it, and start anew.

Comment: A stream can be drained only once. As it is a class variable and drained on the first run of run(), the second call to run() will find an empty stream.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As `audioInputStream` is a class variable and not reinitialized inside the `run()` method the following problem arises.

First call to `run()`:
The `while`loop will read bytes from the `audioInputStream` until it is empty and returns -1.

Second call to `run`:
As `audioInputStream` references the same object - an empty stream - it will return -1 on the first call to `read(...)` and the loop will abort.

One solution to the problem would be to create a new AudioInputStream on each call to run().
Another solution would be to use the mark()/reset() functionality the stream provides.

Create the stream like this:

```
InputStream src = getClass().getResourceAsStream(PATH_TO_SOUND_FILE);
InputStream buffered = new BufferedInputStream(src);
AudioInputStream audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(buffered);

audioInputStream.mark(LENGTH_OF_STREAM_IN_BYTES); // you have to specify this here.
```

It is important that you use a BufferedInputStream. Now you can use

```
audioInputStream.reset();
```

in your `run()` method.

Check http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/AudioInputStream.html#reset() for details.

Comment: Tanks a lot , it's working fine. But won't it affect the time complexity of my program? Isn't there a way to initialize it only once ?

Comment: Complexity of object creation should be O(1), iterating is O(n). So time-complexity should not be an issue. Nevertheless there is an option to reset the stream, I will update the answer.